# Controlling User Skills - Delve

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service, delve

I would like to start implementing employee skill management in 365. I understand each user can edit his/her own skills in the delve profile page. But how can I ,as the global admin, control other users' skills ? most of the fields are editable in the User Profiles management page but skills is not.
I don't want to rely upon users updating the content of this field' because they can't be bothered with it

Gali[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fields in classic user profile settings are editable, even if the textboxes are not visible.
Just type next to the **Skills** and the keywords will be accepted.

[image]

[image]

It might take a long time for the change to take effect in Delve though, possibly up to **72** hours, according to the sync process mentioned in [official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/delve-for-office-365-admins#help-users-troubleshoot-delve) and also this [article](https://blog.hyperfish.com/where-does-the-profile-information-come-from-in-office-365).

Comment: Thanks', this is great. very helpful!!

Comment: @user192724 Glad it helps. Would you please accept it as answer if you later confirm it to be the solution? It will help others in this forum to find answers quickly as well.